# Custom splash screen using JWindow/JPanel doesn't load image correctly when attempting to display it a second time

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen

Thank you in advance for any attempts at trying to help me figure this one out. I've searched all over stack and google and haven't been able to find anything similar to the problem I am having.

I am designing a small program using NetBeans that switches between multiple frames

```
login screen > settings screen > main screen
```

My program can take a while in-between frames to load the next one due to a large amount of frame initialization code. To prevent it from looking like the program is unresponsive. I wrote code which displays an intermediary splash screen `JWindow` which performs all the initialization for the next frame. I realize that there is a splash screen class, but I could not get it to work as desired, this custom implementation of mine does almost everything I need except when I attempt to display the splash screen a second time, during a single program run, the image does not show up on the `JWindow`.

So `run program >  splash screen (works) > login > splash screen (image does not load) > settings`.

Here is a sample clip of code which displays the splash screen `JWindow`:

```
public class Splash extends JPanel {

    private static Calendar date;
    private static long startTime;
    private static final long MAX_TIME = 3000l;
    public static final int LOAD_LOGIN = 0;
    public static final int LOAD_SETTINGS = 1;
    public static JWindow win;
    private final ImageIcon img;

    public Splash() {
        date = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"), Locale.ENGLISH);
        img = new ImageIcon("loader.gif");
        startTime = date.getTimeInMillis();
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        win = new JWindow();
        win.setSize(300, 300);
        win.getContentPane().add(this);
        Login.centerWindow(win); // method from login class that centers window
        win.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void runSplash(int flag) {

        if (flag == LOAD_LOGIN)
            firstRunCheck();
        else {
            initSettings();
        }

        long currTime = date.getTimeInMillis();

        // holds splash display for at least 3 secs
        while ((currTime - startTime) < MAX_TIME) {
            currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        win.dispose(); // has been replaced with win.setVisible(false) before,
                        // same problem
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        //I have read several other questions and sample codes on stack and google
        but using this method is the only way for me to get the animated gif image to
        load correctly

        g2.drawImage(img.getImage(), null, this);

    }

}
```

In order to display this splash screen I instantiate it using `new Splash().runSplash(value);` where value runs the method that loads the following frames required values.

When I first begin run the program everything works perfectly. When I attempt to move from the login screen to the settings screen the `JWindow` loads but it just displays as a blank frame.

The program works fine still, the settings frame eventually loads, but the image never shows up and the window just closes. I am unsure as to what the problem is the class is instantiated the exact same way as the first time.

I suspect perhaps I may be incorrectly disposing of resources, but `win.dispose()` appears to be the correct method according to some of the other problems I have read.

Any help is appreciated thank you.

UPDATE: I am still attempting to resolve this problem. I have used a variety of different implementations to display the splash screen. I have used implementations which use a `JLabel` instead of `JPanel`, and use `setIcon` instead of overriding `paintComponent`. But the same result is observed whenever the implemented splash screen class is called a second time the image does not appear. Since different implementations are also not working I can only assume that that perhaps I have too many events in the event queue or something. To clarify.

My main method is in the `Splash` class detailed above. I call the class in the main method using `new Splash.runSplash(value)`. This call works perfectly. I then call the login `JFrame` using:

```
if (value == LOAD_LOGIN) //RUN_LOGIN is a final variable int
{
   java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
   {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
             /* I have also tried this without the invokeLater 
             command and simply using new Login().setVisible(true). 
             The program still runs fine, but the image still 
             does not display */

             new Login().setVisible(true);                
        }
   });    
}
```

This call is made at the end of the `runSplash(value)` method. After the user inputs the correct login information they are taken to the splash screen again using `new Splash().runSplash(value)` on this call however I cannot get the image to show up on the JWindow.

Comment: let me recommend you not to use multiple `JFrames` because [this problems can occur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657) be sure to read it. Instead, you could use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). I'll test your code right now and try to help you, using multiple `JFrames` (which as I repeat, don't recommend)

Comment: This is my first gui application and I figured, because I was using netbeans, and creating new frames is so simple that this would probably be the common practice. I will certainly note this as bad practice in the future.

Answer (score 0):

dispose() method releases the resource. to be able to use it again you have to use setVisible(false) and when you be sure that your code will not use this window again then only  use dispose().In your case after first splash just use setVisible(False) and dispose after the second time when setting frame loads if you really want it so.

Comment: Thank you Vimlesh for your quick response. When I call dispose does it not release the resources for that particular instance? When I call it a second time using `new Splash(value)` does it not create a whole new instance? But I did try what you suggested and replaced the `win.dispose()` with `win.setVisible(false)` but the I get the same result unfortunately.